# Automatic marshalling of native, blittable structures

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I am writing a wrapper for a mid-sized C library containing mostly small blittable structures.

I have written several wrappers in the past, and they were of 3 types.

1. C# wrapper using P/Invoke.
2. C++/CLI thin wrapper.
3. C++/CLI fat wrapper.

In the C# wrappers, we write managed equivalents of types and function signatures. when we call these managed equivalent functions the Marshaller will translate parameters and return values from the native types into the managed types.

In the C++/CLI thin wrapper, we generally use the encapsulated pointer idiom, where we write managed types containing a pointer to the native type. The C# use the managed types and the API exposed by the wrapper. The C++/CLI wrapper manually encapsulate and decapsulate values at each transition, before and after calling the native function.

In the C++/CLI fat wrapper, we leverage the fact that the C++/CLI layer can directly manipulate the native types and call the native functions and we relocate the intelligence here. This leaves a tighter API surface to the C# client code, at the cost of possibly hiding some features exposed by the original library.

Question:

Is there an automatic marshalling mechanism in C++/CLI akin to what explicit P/Invoke does, whereby managed types are automatically copied to native types and back?

What I consider is the following:

1. In the C++/CLI layer, write managed equivalent of small blittable types. Not mere containers for a pointer but complete structures with the same layout as the native ones, basically the same thing that we do in C# but using the C++/CLI syntax.
2. Have a way to automatically marshall these types to their native equivalent when calling native functions. So that I don't need to call a constructor or a dedicated converter.

The Marshaller in explicit P/Inovke is capable of doing it, can't we do it in C++/CLI?

Example (these would be scattered in various files obviously):

```
struct NativeType
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

NativeType NativeFunction(NativeType foo)
{
    return foo;
}

public value struct ManagedType
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Somewhere in my managed C++/CLI wrapper, I want to do something like:

```
ManagedType ManagedFunction(ManagedType foo)
{
    return NativeFunction(foo);
}
```

The C++/CLI would expose a managed API thinly wrapping the native one, without the boilerplate.

Is this possible?

Comment: Common question.  No, the layout of a managed type is entirely undiscoverable.  Both at compile-time and run-time.  A compiler cannot generate code for this if it doesn't know the layout, an explicit run-time conversion is required.  It tends to be predictable whether a type is blittable, there are however very unintuitive corner-cases.  Already covered pretty well in [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164450/how-to-use-c-c-struct-in-c-sharp-code).

Comment: @HansPassant I guess what is confusing me is that the CLR marshaler is perfectly able to do it when using explicit P/Invoke from C#. Can't we have at least the same level of automation in C++/CLI?

Comment: You could pin the managed struct and get the address of the pinned blittable structure. Pass that to the native functions.