# C# Why do class fields of struct types take up more space than the size of the struct?

Tags: c#, struct, field, sizeof

With a struct that only contains a single `byte` field, I expected that struct to consume 1 byte in memory. If I create an array of that struct type, that turns out to be an accurate expectation. I had the same expectation when using that struct as a field in a class, however, to my surprise, each field consumes the size of an `IntPtr`! I thought that would only happen due to padding the class to the next word size, but it seems to be the case no matter what. Why is this?

[Edit] Updated measurements

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AllocOneByte | 7.453 ns | 0.0885 ns | 0.0827 ns | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocTwoBytes | 8.394 ns | 0.0873 ns | 0.0816 ns | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocThreeBytes | 8.398 ns | 0.0559 ns | 0.0523 ns | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocOneByteWrapper | 8.373 ns | 0.0934 ns | 0.0873 ns | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocTwoByteWrappers | 9.815 ns | 0.1256 ns | 0.1175 ns | 0.0102 | - | - | 32 B |
| AllocThreeByteWrappers | 11.274 ns | 0.1527 ns | 0.1429 ns | 0.0127 | - | - | 40 B |
| AllocOneByteArray | 9.286 ns | 0.1609 ns | 0.1505 ns | 0.0102 | - | - | 32 B |
| AllocTwoBytesArray | 9.396 ns | 0.1038 ns | 0.0920 ns | 0.0102 | - | - | 32 B |
| AllocThreeBytesArray | 8.904 ns | 0.1183 ns | 0.1107 ns | 0.0102 | - | - | 32 B |

---

```
public class Benchmark
{
    public class OneByte
    {
        public byte num;
    }

    public class TwoBytes
    {
        public byte num;
        public byte num2;
    }

    public class ThreeBytes
    {
        public byte num;
        public byte num2;
        public byte num3;
    }


    public struct ByteWrapper
    {
        public byte num;
    }

    public class OneByteWrapper
    {
        public ByteWrapper num;
    }

    public class TwoByteWrappers
    {
        public ByteWrapper num;
        public ByteWrapper num2;
    }

    public class ThreeByteWrappers
    {
        public ByteWrapper num;
        public ByteWrapper num2;
        public ByteWrapper num3;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public OneByte AllocOneByte()
    {
        return new OneByte();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public TwoBytes AllocTwoBytes()
    {
        return new TwoBytes();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ThreeBytes AllocThreeBytes()
    {
        return new ThreeBytes();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public OneByteWrapper AllocOneByteWrapper()
    {
        return new OneByteWrapper();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public TwoByteWrappers AllocTwoByteWrappers()
    {
        return new TwoByteWrappers();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ThreeByteWrappers AllocThreeByteWrappers()
    {
        return new ThreeByteWrappers();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ByteWrapper[] AllocOneByteArray()
    {
        return new ByteWrapper[1];
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ByteWrapper[] AllocTwoBytesArray()
    {
        return new ByteWrapper[2];
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ByteWrapper[] AllocThreeBytesArray()
    {
        return new ByteWrapper[3];
    }
}
```

[Edit2] This is not the same as [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member). This is about using small structs as fields in a class.

Comment: CPU's are faster at loading values that align with the native word size. aka memory alignment.

Comment: That's not really an explanation for this considering if I do `public byte num, num2, num3;` it will pack the bytes efficiently and not allocate a whole IntPtr for each byte.

Comment: Some more reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742325/why-does-struct-alignment-depend-on-whether-a-field-type-is-primitive-or-user-de

Comment: Pretty sure C# follows C struct padding rules. `struct alignment == max(field alignment)`, inserting padding to ensure fields are aligned, including at the end. Otherwise the alignment would be off inside an array. So `sizeof(struct {int* p; byte b;}) == sizeof(struct {int* p; int* p2;})`. And a class object contains pointers.

Comment: c# is managed and every object is wrapped with a type.  So the data inside a struct is continuous to be backward compatible with straight c language, but the struct has a header that is added in c#.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman padding rules for a type do not explain why simple structs like this are bloated in size. Otherwise `byte` fields would also consume 8 bytes (which they don't).

@jdweng That's not true, structs do not have the type overhead. Only classes have that overhead. Structs are designed to consume only as much space as their fields (plus necessary padding).

Comment: @Tim the alignment of `byte` is 1 so obviously it only needs to consume 1 byte, similarly a struct of `short`s or `long` will consume a multiple of 2 and 8 respectively

Comment: the dupe is not in C# but the reason is exactly the same

Comment: @phuclv I'm well aware of padding. The rules for padding with structs containing primitives and other struct fields are clear that a simple ByteWrapper struct should have a size of 1 byte. When a ByteWrapper[1] is created, it consumes array overhead + 1 byte + 7 bytes padding, and when creating larger arrays up to 8, it consumes the same amount of memory. When one ByteWrapper is placed in a class, it should follow the same behavior and take up class overhead + 1 byte with 7 bytes padding. Adding more ByteWrapper fields up to 8 should not consume more memory.

Comment: Did you try the `[StructLayout]` attribute? This allows specifying the padding.

Comment: @PMF I tried `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, Pack = X)]` with X = 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 and those all had no effect. I also tried `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` which actually _did_ manage to pack efficiently, but of course I get a warning with partial classes (it does still work with partials, interestingly, so I wonder how it would handle more complex partial classes, but I'm not sure if that's safe in all runtimes (considering the warning)). I also don't think I can use `LayoutKind.Explicit` with reference fields.

Comment: @jdweng structs absolutely do **not** have a header. Unless you're talking about boxing, but the question is not about boxing.

Comment: @Tim on the comment above: you *can* use explicit layout on reference fields, but they still need to be aligned; it also gets *really messy* to do so if your code might work on both x64 and x86, so  in reality: people don't tend to, unless they only have one reference field, which they can whack at the end of the struct

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. The "associated question" is not the same as this one.

Comment: @MarcGravell :Yes I'm referring to boxing.  Boxing would be the reason for the alignment and extra characters the way the OP is describing what is happening.

Comment: @jdweng sometimes I'm not as observant as I should be; could you please be explicit about which box you're referring to? I've read the OP's post 3 times, and I can't see a single boxing operation. I don't think this has anything whatsoever to do with boxing, but I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: @MarcGravell:Ths OP says "each field consumes the size of an IntPtr".  The OP expects one byte but actually get 4 bytes (size of IntPtr).  The 3 extra bytes are due to boxing.

Comment: @jdweng show me the box; there are *zero* boxes in the code shown

Comment: @MarcGravell : The ByteWrapper structure would be boxed.

Comment: @jdweng exactly where? I see precisely zero boxes; let's be explicit: a box is when a value-type is cast into an `object` type (including casting to an interface type); please show me the box

Comment: @MarcGravell : How would you see the boxing in source code?  Normally the boxes are invisible in the source.

Comment: @jdweng most are pretty obvious, but the real answer is by looking at the IL; there are zero IL boxing instructions in OP's code

Comment: @MarcGravell: I didn't look at the IL. Would IL vary in Net vs Core?

Comment: @jdweng Wrapping a value in a struct does not box that value. It just encapsulates it (ideally without increasing memory footprint).

Comment: @jdweng there are no relevant IL changes between netfx and .NET Core (onwards) - actually, IL changes very little - the only time I remember huge changes was for generics in 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I realise in the comments you say that you're well aware of padding, but in general: this is simply: padding. To take more fine-grained control and avoid this, you can use `[FieldOffset(...)]` (if you need to avoid padding between fields of different types), and `[StructLayout(...)]` (to control the defined size of individual structs). Fundamentally `ByteWrapper` is being padded to the word size by default. You can convince it not to do this, using `[StructLayout]`.

FWIW: for me, `ByteWrapper` comes out at 1 byte, and `ThreeByteWrappers` comes out at 8 bytes - as does `ThreeBytes`.

Comment: What if I have a partial class with an object reference field and a ByteWrapper field in 2 parts (so 2 reference and 2 struct fields)? Is there a way to use the FieldOffsetAttribute to efficiently pack those?

Comment: I guess efficient packing is not possible with generic struct fields, which is rather unfortunate.

Comment: @Tim reference fields *must* be word aligned; so even if you only use 9 bytes in the struct (assuming reference then the byte), you can't smoosh 2 of them back to back, because the references wouldn't be correctly aligned

Comment: "FWIW: for me, ByteWrapper comes out at 1 byte, and ThreeByteWrappers comes out at 8 bytes - as does ThreeBytes." What runtime are you running that on? I ran this on .Net 5.0 64-bit.

Comment: @Tim net5, but I also tested on net48 to see if it made a difference

Comment: @Tim minor note from history: the (object, small-primitive)x2 thing was very relevant recently in a change to how `ReadOnlySequence<T>` works; it *was* defined by two `Position` structs (start and end), where a `Position` is an `object` and an `int` - which means it took 32 bytes on x64 (16 bytes on x86) since each reference needed to be aligned, but it is *now* changed to be "start obj, end obj, start offset, end offset", which means it now only takes 24 bytes on x64 (still 16 bytes on x86). So: a case in point - sometimes, to pack *efficiently*, you need to sacrifice a little encapsulation.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well, whether reference fields must be word aligned would technically depend on the target platform. X86/X64 CPUs have no alignment requirement at all, but most other CPUs do. But making the struct layout depend on the _target_ hardware would make the code platform dependent.

Comment: "sometimes, to pack efficiently, you need to sacrifice a little encapsulation" - this was exactly my next thought to solve this problem. Use a primitive field and pass it by ref to the implementation. Ugly, but I suppose that should work as long as it's only private code doing that.

Comment: @PMF I'm not talking about the CPU - I'm talking about the runtime; I haven't managed to find a hard reference in the CLI specification about whether that should or shouldn't be legal, but that is irrelevant: the current runtimes do not support it - throwing `TypeLoadException` "Could not load type '{foo}' from assembly '{bar}' because it contains an object field at offset {offset} that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field" (there is a clear CLI specification rule that the second scenario mentioned is indeed illegal, note - in ECMA 335 II.10.7)

Comment: @PMF also note: I'm not talking about the *value* of the reference not being aligned; I'm talking about the field that *holds* the reference not being aligned

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the fact that the CLI has extra requirements on this.

Answer (score -1):

It's certainly not ideal, but I managed to get around this issue by wrapping the small struct fields inside another struct.

```cs
public class Benchmark
{
    public struct ByteWrapper
    {
        public byte num;
    }

    public class OneByteWrapper
    {
        public ByteWrapper num;
    }

    public class TwoByteWrappers
    {
        public struct SmallFields
        {
            public ByteWrapper num;
            public ByteWrapper num2;
        }

        public SmallFields smallFields;
    }

    public class ThreeByteWrappers
    {
        public struct SmallFields
        {
            public ByteWrapper num;
            public ByteWrapper num2;
            public ByteWrapper num3;
        }

        public SmallFields smallFields;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public OneByteWrapper AllocOneByteWrapper()
    {
        return new OneByteWrapper();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public TwoByteWrappers AllocTwoByteWrappers()
    {
        return new TwoByteWrappers();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public ThreeByteWrappers AllocThreeByteWrappers()
    {
        return new ThreeByteWrappers();
    }
}
```

| Method | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AllocOneByteWrapper | .NET 4.8 | 9.747 ns | 0.0903 ns | 0.0844 ns | 1.00 | 0.0306 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocOneByteWrapper | .NET Core 5.0 | 9.787 ns | 0.1139 ns | 0.0951 ns | 1.00 | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| AllocTwoByteWrappers | .NET 4.8 | 9.975 ns | 0.0655 ns | 0.0580 ns | 1.05 | 0.0306 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocTwoByteWrappers | .NET Core 5.0 | 9.474 ns | 0.1106 ns | 0.0981 ns | 1.00 | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| AllocThreeByteWrappers | .NET 4.8 | 9.483 ns | 0.0535 ns | 0.0474 ns | 1.00 | 0.0306 | - | - | 24 B |
| AllocThreeByteWrappers | .NET Core 5.0 | 9.446 ns | 0.1235 ns | 0.1031 ns | 1.00 | 0.0076 | - | - | 24 B |