# How to view the memory size and layout of a specific managed C# reference type?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like some tool or method of viewing the size and layout in memory of a specific C# managed reference type, including all of its instance fields. Obviously this is an implementation detail and my program itself doesn't need to know it, but I, the human programmer, would like to understand how the CLR organizes the actual memory layouts of certain of my C# classes for the purposes of optimization and curiosity. (I've read articles and understand the high-level theory about the memory layout of C# objects, but I would like to see the how the CLR actually does it in-practice.)

If it matters, I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24744714/17034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [SOS Debugging Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/sos-debugging-extension) which has a `DumpClass` command. This dumps out information about the `EEClass` structure for a type, which includes e.g. what offset each field is located at.

Comment: Thanks! It took some figuring out, but this is exactly the kind of tool I was looking for.

Comment: For anyone else reading this wanting a bit more direction, here are the steps:
1) Install the [dotnet-dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump#dotnet-dump-collect) tool
2) Run `dotnet-dump collect` to create a dump file of the desired process.
3) Run `dotnet-dump analyze` to analyze that dump file.
4) Run the `name2ee` command to get the EEClass value for the class in question.
5) Run the `dumpclass` command to print out a list of all instance fields, including the byte offset of each. (Note they are NOT printed in byte offset order.)